# How to write sub query in Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Following is my MySQL query

```
SELECT id 
FROM member_measurement_records 
WHERE date in (SELECT MAX(date) from member_measurement_records GROUP BY type)
```

Which I want to write using laravel eloquent. 
Can you please help me. As I am new to this.

Comment: Have you created models for each table?

Comment: @Suraj yes I have created models for each table

Comment: Answering this is entirely dependant on what you named your models. Would you share them in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are several ways to do it.

Using DB facade

```
$data = DB::table('member_measurement_records')->where('date', DB::raw("(select max(`date`) from member_measurement_records GROUP BY type)"))->get();
```

Using eloquent and raw query

```
$data = MemberMeasurementRecords::whereRaw('date = (select max(`date`) from member_measurement_records GROUP BY type)')->get();
```

Using Eloquent and DB facade

```
$data = MemberMeasurementRecords::find(DB::table('member_measurement_records')->max('date')->groupBy('type'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it, but you can try it:

(It is assumend your corresponding model is called `MemberMeasurementRecords`)

```
MemberMeasurementRecords::whereIn('date', function ($query) {
            $query->max('date')->orderBy('type');
        })->get('id');
```

Comment: using subquery here is great